# Removing unused google apps

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-apps, sony-xperia-z2

I installed a custom ROM and flashed [Open Gapps Aroma](https://github.com/opengapps/opengapps/wiki/Aroma-Package). I was excited by the options to remove or exclude various features I never use (such as Google's calculator, Google Books, Google's clock, stock wallpaper etc) but unfortunately the installer had a bug and would only work if I installed everything.

How do I completely remove google apps that I don't need?

Comment: Is the custom rom pre-rooted?

Comment: Use Aroma File Manager to explore `/system/app` and `/system/priv-app` and delete what you don't need, or if it's TWRP, use the built-in file manager. The OS doesn't have to be rooted.

Comment: @RyanNoles yes CM 12.1

Comment: Did you ever get the apps removed?

Comment: @RyanNoles no I'm actually considering reflashing and using mini gapps https://github.com/opengapps/opengapps/wiki/Mini-Package